# Android eclipse Images for small screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

Folks,

I am very new to Android,so please forgive me if I am asking a silly question,

I am developing an app, and I have some images in drawable folder, and under layout\ folder there is xml file activity_main.xml, which points to this above drawable folder, for images

```
          <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
            >
```

Now for small screen(ldpi (low) ~120dpi) I've used drawable-ldpi folder that contain images pertaining to small screen, now my question is for ldpi we have activity_main.xml file under       layout-small\ folder, but this activity_main.xml should this point to drawable folder or should this point to images in  drawable-ldpi folder? and how?

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look on [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: ok Dhaval :) I'll read that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Android will do the job of finding the correct image for your resolution for you. Don't worry about it. What I mean is that you can point to `@drawable/image` and the Android does the rest.

Comment: <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
            >

then for  android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle" line which folder should I mention for small screen?

Comment: you can use android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle" and android will automatically find the correct image at runtime!

Comment: Thanks Bojan, if thats the case then, I wouldn't worry to much ! !

Thanks.